# HAML and mistake in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm learning HAML and I have a problem with from_for

```
%b New Advert!

- form_for @car, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f|
  = f.text_field :body 
  = f.submit t('advert.form.save')
```

My Controller advert_controller

```
class AdvertController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def create
    @car = Car.new(params[:car])
  end
end
```

And my model car.rb

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

But I have a mistake:

undefined method `body' for #

NoMethodError in Advert#new

Showing /my_project/app/views/advert/new.html.haml where line #4 raised

**UPD** form_for with '=' doesn't work

```
= form_for @car, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f|
      = f.text_field :body 
      = f.submit t('advert.form.save')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two errors here :
first you should use `=` instead of `-` for `form_form`, indeed `=` will output the result whereas `-` won't.

As `form_for` returns HTML for the form, you want it to be written on the page ;)

As for the cause of your error, well I'm not entirely sure, but it seems that your `Car` model doeesn't have a `body` field and so it does not have a `body` method

Comment: My Car model has a body field

Comment: are you sur you ran migrations ? because having a body in attr_accessible is not enough, your `cars`table needs to have a `body` column

Comment: actually `attr_accesible` is not necessary at all if the database table is correct

Comment: @froderik I don't know what you're talking about, but what you say is just wrong, attr_accessible has nothing to do with the table structure, it's about mass assignment